# The best overloaded method match has some invalid Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public JsonResult CreateNewMember(MembersModel m)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new DbEntityDataModel())
        {
            ***var EmpAdd = db.tblMembers.Add(m);***  
            return Json(new { Result = "Error", Records = EmpAdd });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "Error", Message = EX });
    }
}
```

I get this error while inserting into db. I have highlighted the part

> Cannot convert from 'Mvcapps.Models.MembersModel' to 'Mvcapps.Models.tblMember'

The other day I have written like this but it worked

```
public JsonResult CreateRecord(Person objperson)
{
        try
        {
            using (var db = new VIVEK_ROOPASOFTEntities1())
            {
                var addedPerson = db.Persons.Add(objperson);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = addedPerson }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
}

public class MembersModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Pasword { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PinCode { get; set; }
}
```

Here is `tblMember`

```
namespace Mvcapps.Models
{
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   public partial class tblMember
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string Gender { get; set; }
       public string Mobile { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public string Pasword { get; set; }
       public string Country { get; set; }
       public string City { get; set; }
       public string PinCode { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was hoping that MembersModel had a tblMember property. What's the definition of the tblMember class?

Comment: tblMember is just a Database table

Comment: Importantly, no it's not! The message "Cannot convert from 'Mvcapps.Models.MembersModel' to 'Mvcapps.Models.tblMember'" is telling you that rows of the database table tblMember are repesented by Mvcapps.Models.tblMember. Look for that in your solution...

Comment: i have added it to the code

Comment: Yep, so C# doesn't automatically know that MembersModel and tblMembers have the same properties or that they mean the same thing. You either have to add a conversion, manually map one to the other (as in my answer) or if you don't want to do those things for some reason then you could use AutoMapper (but even then you would have to define that ModelMember maps to tblMember).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment on the question itself. Entity Framework represents database tables as classes in your project. The error message you're receiving is telling you that EF doesn't know how to turn MembersModel into a tblMember so that it can then save that data to the DB.

---

As @marc_s says you need to convert from MembersModel to tblMember yourself.

Assuming that you already know that the MembersModel you receive is definitely new and you don't have to check that it exists. I'd do something like

```
public JsonResult CreateNewMember(MembersModel m)
{
    try
    {
        var newTblMember = new tblMember
                                 {
                                   Id = m.Id,
                                   FirstName = m.FirstName,
                                   LastName = m.LastName,
                                   // and so on for the other properties
                                  };
        using (var db = new DbEntityDataModel())
        {
            var EmpAdd = db.tblMembers.Add(newTblMember);  
            return Json(new { Result = "Error", Records = EmpAdd });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "Error", Message = EX });
    }
}
```

Because db.tblMembers is a collection of type tblMember and there is no implicit or explicit conversion between MembersModel and tblMember you have to convert it yourself. [You can create conversions yourself if you want to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The `db.tblMembers` is a collection of type `tblMember` - what you're trying to store into it is of type `MembersModel` - that's **not the same thing** (not the same class).

That's exactly what the error says - it cannot automatically convert something from `MembersModel` (your parameter `m`) into `tblMember` - you'll need to do the conversion yourself!

Comment: the other day i hav written the following its worked fine                              public JsonResult CreateRecord(Person objperson)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new VIVEK_ROOPASOFTEntities1())
                {
                    var addedPerson = db.Persons.Add(objperson);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = addedPerson }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                }


            }

Comment: @Vivekh maybe if you add the code for MembersModel to the question someone can give a more thorough answer but this answer is clearly explaining your problem.

Comment: @Vivekh: which - again - clearly shows you have **two different object types** - those are **not the same** - you need to convert from one to the other, as the error clearly states ....